# Phaser P2 Collision

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to have my bullets group that already collides with the enemies, both of them are a group, but now that I want to add a static block or obstacle, it simply wont collide or overlap or nothing, what I want is that when the bullet collides or overlaps it gets destroyed or at least bounce into the obstacle, see code below:

```js
////////////////My Bullets//////////These work fine and collide correctly with my enemies.//////

 createBullets: function() {
        
    this.bullets = this.game.add.group();
    this.bullets.enableBody = true;
    this.bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;
    this.bullets.createMultiple(100, 'bulletSprite', 0, false);
    this.bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
    this.bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5);
    this.bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
    this.bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true); 
        
       
    },
    
    fireBullet: function(){ 

   if (this.bulletTimer < this.game.time.time) {
            this.bulletTimer = this.game.time.time + 500;
            this.bullet = this.bullets.getFirstExists(false);
        if (this.bullet) {
            this.bullet.reset(this.tanke.x, this.tanke.y - 20);
            this.bullet.body.setCollisionGroup(this.bulletCG);
             this.bullet.body.collides([this.figuraCG]);
            this.bullet.body.velocity.y = -3500;
            }
        }

    },


//////This is the block or obstacle this just wont work no matter what I try///////////


makeOneBloque: function(){
        
        
        
        this.bloque = this.game.add.sprite(500, 950, 'Blokes');  
        
         
        this.bloque.enableBody = true;
      
        
        this.game.physics.p2.enable(this.bloque, true);
        
        this.bloque.body.kinematic = true;  
       
        
        this.bloque.body.collides(this.bullets, this.collisionBulletBloque, this); //////I tried overlaps and it just crashes the lvl
       
       
      
       
         


    },
    
      collisionBulletBloque: function(bullet) {
        
         
      
        bullet.sprite.destroy();


        
    },
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

////Try this on this part use it like so Im not shure If it'll work havent tried it myself with your code but give it a shoot and let me know!

```
game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.bloque.body.collides, this.bullets, this.collisionBulletBloque, null, this);
```

//////I tried overlaps and it just crashes the lvl